# Class won't work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning to work with classes in VBA. I'm attempting to write one that gets the true used range. My code in the class module looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private mySheet As Range

Public Property Get clTrueUsedRange() As Range
    Set clTrueUsedRange = TrueUsedRange(mySheet)
End Property

Public Property Let clTrueUsedRange(ByRef wsSource As Range)
    mySheet = wsSource
End Property
Private Function TrueUsedRange(ByRef wsSource As Worksheet) As Range
Dim rLastCell As Range

With wsSource
    Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    Set TrueUsedRange = .Range("$A$1:" & rLastCell.Address)
End With

End Function
```

When I try to run it, I get an error message, stating: ByRef Type mismatch

**What is not correct in my refrences in the code?**

Comment: `TrueUsedRange` expects a Worksheet as a parameter but you are passing an Integer for some reason.

Comment: @Rory Fixed that. Now I get `Object Variable or With block not set`

Comment: Where do you assign a worksheet to the variable?

Comment: From a Sub. I use the following: `rData.clTrueUsedRange = ActiveSheet.Cells`

Comment: I'm assigning all the cells on the worksheet as a range. Would have preferred to simply use the specified worksheet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function expects a sheet, not a `Range`. You need: `Set clTrueUsedRange = TrueUsedRange(mySheet.Worksheet)` or change your code as below, and pass a Worksheet when you call it. Also, your `Property Let` needs to be a `Property Set` as you are assigning an Object:

```
Option Explicit
Private mySheet As Worksheet

Public Property Get clTrueUsedRange() As Range
    Set clTrueUsedRange = TrueUsedRange(mySheet)
End Property

Public Property Set Sheet(ByRef wsSource As Worksheet)
    Set mySheet = wsSource
End Property
Private Function TrueUsedRange(ByRef wsSource As Worksheet) As Range
Dim rLastCell As Range

With wsSource
    Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    Set TrueUsedRange = .Range("$A$1:" & rLastCell.Address)
End With

End Function
```

and then use:
`Set rData.Sheet = ActiveSheet`

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting much further with this now... it still tells me that I am missing a `Object variable or With block variable` in the Function. Everything seems to be within the `wsSource` with block though??

Comment: Ok. Didn't see your last comment! Thanks a ton!